# Why do these `element` objects have the `search` property?

Tags: javascript

Howdy guys.

I am wondering why does the following code snippet work (tested in the latest Firefox Nightly):

```js
var links = document.querySelectorAll('a[href]');
for (var i = 0; i < links.length; ++i) {
    console.log(links[i].search); // Where does `search` come from?
}
```

As “usual,” I get the query string of the `href` in each `a` element (something I can also do with a simple `substr` or something, but that's not the point); whereas, if I do something like this:

```js
var divs = document.querySelectorAll('div');
for (var i = 0; i < divs.length; ++i) {
    console.log(divs[i].search);
}
```

All I get is `undefined`.

According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element), there is no such thing as `search` property available for `element` objects (`document.querySelectorAll(selector)` [returns](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Document.querySelectorAll) a non-live `NodeList` of `element` objects). So, where does all this come from?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You're working with [anchor elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLAnchorElement) so you have to look at the proper documentation. Different types of HTML element nodes have different APIs.

Comment: Thank you @Pointy, this makes perfect sense! Can I accept a “comment” as an “answer”?

Comment: I was lazy but I'll type in an answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Different sorts of HTML element nodes in the DOM have different APIs. The nodes corresponding to `<a>` tags implement an API for examining URLs. The "search" property is one of those special type-specific things. Basically an `<a>` node has the same properties as `window.location`, more or less.